# Understanding code for pricing Asian Option

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am looking at the code here for Asian option pricing:

https://github.com/saulwiggin/finance-with-python/blob/master/Monte%20Carlo%20and%20Pricing%20Exotic%20Options/asian-option.py.

Here is the code:

```
import scipy as sp
s0=40. #today stock price
x=40. #excercise price
T=0.5 #maturity in years
r=0.05 #risk-free rate
sigma=0.2 # volatility
n_simulation =100 # number of simulations
n_steps=100
dt=T/n_steps
call=sp.zeros([n_simulation],dtype=float)
for j in range(0, n_simulation):
    sT*=s0
    total=0
for i in range(0,int(n_steps)):
        e=sp.random.normal()
        sT*=sp.exp((r-0.5*sigma*sigma)*dt+sigma*e*sp.sqrt(dt))
        total+=sT
        price_average=total/n_steps
        call[j]=max(price_average-x,0)
        call_price=mean(call)*exp(-r*T)
        print 'call price = ', round(call_price,3)
```

What is the `sT` variable defined as here? I don't see a definition. What is the for loop `for j in range(0, n_simulation)` doing exactly? From context it seems like it should be the stock price at time T. If so how should `sT` be defined?

Thanks.

EDIT: I understand the code is illegal/won't compile, I'm just asking if anyone can help fill in the blanks

Comment: https://github.com/saulwiggin/finance-with-python/issues/new/choose

Comment: Seriously, the code won't even run, so it's not really clear what's intended.

Comment: It's long since time to upgrade to Python 3.x.

Comment: The code never initializes `sT`, so it makes no sense to multiply it by something.

Comment: That code was written 9 years ago.  The odds that the original programmer is still around are low.

Comment: @Barmar I understand the code is illegal, I'm just asking if anyone can help fill in the blanks

Comment: the `for` loop is multiplying `sT` by `s0` `n_simulation` times. So it's multiplying it by `s0 ** n_simulation`.

Comment: In the context of finance, this is calculating compound interest. `s0` is the interest rate, and `n_simulation` is the number of periods.

Comment: Trying to figure out what's going on, I think this should just be `sT = s0`. To price and option, we run multiple scenarios, in each of which the stock price evolves stochastically with geometric Brownian motion. For each simulation run, reinitialise the stock price to its t=0 value of `sT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at figuring out what was intended. Obviously some guesswork and assumptions are involved in this.

The changes involved are:

1. Fixing the line you questioned from `sT*=s0` to `sT = s0` (i.e. at the start of each simulation, reset the current stock price back to today's price)
2. Fixing some indentation so the loops make sense. (Do `j` simulations; in each simulation evolve the price for `i` timesteps and calculate the option payoff; finally average the option payoff over all simulations.)
3. Fixing the line that draws values from the normal distribution.
4. Fixing some imports (to be fair, these might have worked fine in earlier versions of scipy).
5. Fixing the `print` to be Python 3 compatible.

This now runs in Python 3 and prices the call at about $1.50 - $1.60. (Running more simulations would get you tighter bounds on it.)

```
import scipy as sp
import math
import statistics

s0=40. #today stock price
x=40. #excercise price
T=0.5 #maturity in years
r=0.05 #risk-free rate
sigma=0.2 # volatility
n_simulation =100 # number of simulations
n_steps=100
dt=T/n_steps
call=sp.zeros([n_simulation],dtype=float)
for j in range(0, n_simulation):
    sT=s0  # Reset the stock price to its t=0 value for a new simulation
    total=0  # Reset the total for the average price calculation
    for i in range(0,int(n_steps)):
        e, = sp.stats.norm().rvs(1)  # Get one value from normal dist
        sT *= math.exp((r-0.5*sigma*sigma)*dt + sigma*e*sp.sqrt(dt))
        total += sT
    price_average=total/n_steps
    call[j]=max(price_average-x,0)
call_price = statistics.mean(call)*math.exp(-r*T)
print('call price = ', round(call_price,3))
```

In general, I'd gently suggest that a resource isn't the best learning vehicle if the code needs this much massaging in order to run and produce sensible results :)

---

As an alternative, using numpy array operations the same algorithm could be done faster and without explicit `for` loops:

```
import numpy as np

spot = 40
strike = 40
T = 0.5
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.2
n_sims = 100000
n_steps = 100

dt = T / n_steps

# Perform geometric Brownian motion:
# Make a matrix price_factors representing the ratio of each price
# to the previous timestep. We treat rows as representing simulations,
# columns as representing timesteps
rands = np.random.normal(size=(n_sims, n_steps))
price_factors = np.exp((r - sigma * sigma / 2) * dt + sigma * rands * np.sqrt(dt))

# Now calculate the prices using the cumulative product (along the time axis)
# of price_factors
prices = spot * np.cumprod(price_factors, axis=1)

# Calculate the Asian call payoff per simulation
payoffs = np.maximum(0, np.mean(prices, axis=1) - strike)

# Final result is the average over simulations
call_price = np.mean(payoffs)
print(call_price)
```